# Extract the year out of a Date and compare it in the same query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am working on a page that has to display lots of information depending on a year and a type filter. (I will use parametrized queries)

So my query should look something like :

```
SELECT Login FROM LeaveRequest 
WHERE StartDateYear = year 
  AND EndDateYear = year 
  AND Type = typeid
```

But here's the issue, my startDate and endDate are stored in the following format :

```
YYYY-MM-dd
```

Is there a way to extract the year out of these two and compare them with my `year` variable in the same query?

Comment: What do you mean they are stored in this format? Are they stored as `datetime` or `varchar`?

Comment: Are the startdate and enddate fields  in the datetime format?

Comment: They are in a `date` format, excuse the lack of precision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Login FROM LeaveRequest 
WHERE StartDateYear = year(convert(date,'2015-11-18',111))
  AND EndDateYear = year(convert(date,'2015-11-18',111))
  AND Type = typeid
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this using the [Year function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186313.aspx):

```
year(StartDateYear) = year AND year(EndDateYear) = year
```

Assuming the column as DateTime. Else you need to first cast the column as datetime